# Invalid domain name identifier specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

When trying to create an `AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping` through CloudFormation, I am given the following error:

```
Invalid domain name identifier specified
```

Below is the portion(s) of my CloudFormation template that should create the `AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping`:

```
{
    "Parameters": {
        "ApiDomainName": {
            "Description": "The domain name for the API",
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "ApiBasePathMapping": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping",
            "Properties": {
                "DomainName": {
                    "Ref": "ApiDomainName"   
                },
                "RestApiId": {
                    "Ref": "RepositoryApi"
                },
                "Stage": {
                    "Ref": "ApiProductionStage"
                }
            },
            "DependsOn": [
                "ApiProductionStage"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-basepathmapping.html) makes no mention that it needs to be anything special for the `DomainName`, but the documentation for this resource seems to be lacking some information (It doesn't list outputs for example even though there is a `Distribution Domain Name` created as an example).

The remainder of the stack works as expected. I am trying to add this resource in as a Change Set. I do own the domain I am trying to use, and I have created a certificate in ACM for this domain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting from AWS forums:

> You can only create or modify base path mappings after the domain name
>   has been added to API Gateway. This "Invalid domain name identifier
>   specified" error message is returned when the domain name given in the
>   base path mapping is not found, indicating that it has not been added
>   yet.

Also, as of March 2017, the only way to add domain name to the API Gateway via CloudFormation is via custom resources that CloudFormation offers.

Ref: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=769627

Comment: I don't know how I missed that one. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

It is now possible to just do that. You just have to explicit state on your CFN template that there is a dependency (`DependsOn`):

```
...
ApiDevMapping:
  Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping'
  Properties:
    BasePath: v1.0
    Stage: dev
    DomainName: my-api.example.com
    RestApiId: !Ref MobileApiDev
DependsOn:
  - MobileApiDevDomain
...
```